# Enable Single Sign On for Sitecore Intranet

Tags: sitecore, single-sign-on

I am trying to enable a single-sign-on for a sitecore website.

I have installed and configured the Sitecore AD module. 
( as instructed here : http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/ad/sitecore_active_directory_module_guide_sc62-65-usletter.pdf )

This made it possible to use a single-sign-on for the sitecore CMS functionality. 
But on the actual website this doesn't seem to help me out.
Users should be automatically logged in ( single-sign-on )

Anyone know how i can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The AD module will connect you to Active Directory and the instructions for the module will show you how authors can sign in automatically to the content management interface. This is the primary purpose of the Active Directory module.

That being said, you can also use it for end-user SSO if that is your goal. I've accomplished this in the past by setting up some .NET code in the Session_Start of the Global.asax to extract the current user's credentials and then log them in using the AuthenticationManager.

There is a similar question on SO with suggested solutions that can be found here: [Sitecore with LDAP - authenticate programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26870435/sitecore-with-ldap-authenticate-programmatically)

Comment: I've tried your solution but Context.Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]; simply returns "".
( This code was put in Session_Start method of the global.asax and i have windows authentication enabled in IIS. )